# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm the getting the error 'SyntaxError: can't assign to function call' when I try to run this code, and I can't figure out what to change since this code worked for the person showing me.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
BTC= pd.DataFrame(BTC, columns=['Open time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close time', 'Quote asset volume', 'Number of trades', 'Taker buy asset volume', 'taker buy quote asset volume', 'Ignore'])
BTC['Open time'] = pd.to_datetime(BTC['Open time']), unit='ms'
BTC.set_index('Open time',inplace=True)
BTC
```

The error is pointed to the third line.

```
BTC['Open time'] = pd.to_datetime(BTC['Open time']), unit='ms'
```

I'm thinking maybe some syntax in the wrapper has changed since the code i got is a couple of years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `unit` attribute *inside* the brackets:

```
BTC['Open time'] = pd.to_datetime(BTC['Open time']), unit='ms'
```

to

```
BTC['Open time'] = pd.to_datetime(BTC['Open time'], unit='ms')
```

Comment: To expand a bit: `a = b = c` is the same as `a = c; b = c`, and `x, y` is equivalent to `(x, y)`. So the exception happens because the code tries to do `(pd.to_datetime(BTC['Open time']), unit) = 'ms'`, in particular `pd.to_datetime(BTC['Open time']) = 'm'`, which is of course invalid.

Adding this as a comment because I was super confused as to where "can't assign to function call" comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I think an assignment statement does not give a value in Python.
So,

> , unit='ms'

is not valid.